# Exception management in AsynchronousFileChannel.read(...)

Tags: java, file-io, asynchronous, exception

`java.nio.channels.AsynchronousFileChannel` offers two methods to read data from a file:

1. `read(dst, position, attachment, handler)` will call the provided handler when completed
2. `read(dst, position)` returns a `Future` which will allow me to `get()` the result of the operation

The `CompletionHandler` interface specifies a method `failed(Throwable exc, A attachment)`, whereas the `Future` does not. It only has the option to throw an `ExecutionException` from its `get()` method.

***Let's say I read from a file on a flaky disk, and the disk throws an IO-Error, how will this be handled in the two cases?***

Specifically, I have the following 3 questions:

1. Will the `failed()` method on the `CompletionHandler` be called? Or will it indicate the operation as `completed` with a result of `-1`?
2. Will the `get()` method on the `Future` throw an Exception, or will it simply return `-1` as the read result?
3. If `-1` is returned in either case, how can I distinguish between an IO-Error and a simple EOF condition (preferably without a hack like timing the operation)?

For some reason, I can't find any documentation on this...